# Is an item (i.e., scissors) not muktzeh if it's usable for a destructive purpose on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, muktzeh, keilim, makeh-befatish

Many are makpid to [make a hole in a re-closeable bottle](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Opening_bottles_and_cans#cite_note-6) before opening it for the first time on Shabbat. The purpose is to avoid makeh b'patish from making a new vessel when one opens the bottle.

However, in order to make the hole, one would presumably need to use an object ordinarily thought of as muktzeh, such as an awl(?) or scissors. I realize there are alternative solutions, but, in theory, would such puncturing tools still be considered muktzeh, insofar as they could be used on Shabbos for this destructive purpose? Would one be allowed to move/handle such items in general--insofar as they have this possibility--or only when one is using them for this purpose?

Comment: yes screwdriver is good

Answer (score 2):

Objects in this category are called "keilim she'm'lachtam l’issur," which means--according to [this](http://rabbikaganoff.com/tag/kli-shemelachto-lissur/) nice overview of Shabbos 123-124--they may be moved if and only if one needs them (*l'tzorech gufo*) or the place they are occupying (*l'tzorech mikomo*) for a Shabbos-approved use. (Cf. "keilim she'm'lachtam l'heter," which refers to items that may additionally be moved to prevent their damage.)